# Old math fonts with proper math table

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

Recently I found out about a great font that looks exactly like the  fonts in classics such as Hardy's A Course of Pure Mathematics: Century Modern and I used it in my document. I was wondering if there exists a similar font with math support. For example, it would be able to handle delimeters automatically, it should have old looking greek/cal/frak symbols.

I am not sure if posting free fonts is against the rules but here is where I got the fonts:
https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/19970/century-modern-tt-regular
https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/19968/century-modern-tt-italic

This is what the output looks like[image]

Comment: What font are you using (for the text) now? [Old Standard](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/oldstandard/) has partial math support; maybe not everything you're looking for, but letting CM/LM fill in the gaps looks acceptable to me.

Comment: Old Standard does not look good honestly. Also it does not have the old effect in this font. I am using Century Modern Regular+Italic right now

Comment: which font are you using, I don't see "Century Modern" there is [EamesCentury modern](https://www.typewolf.com/eames-century-modern) or [Century Modern FS](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/fontsite/century-modern-fs) or...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle updated the post with links. I was not sure if it was ok to post links to free fonts. But I added them since they do not seem to be commercial. Here is a repo where I have used this: https://github.com/proafxin/elemannt

Comment: Possibly start from TeXGyre Schola, a full opentype Math font derived from the URW clone of New Century Schoolbook, which is part of the wider "Century" font family. You could still specify your preferred font to be used for the basic latin and Greek